# converting pptx to image

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32

```
import win32com.client
import uuid
import os.path
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = True
direc ="./input/"
inputDir = os.listdir(direc)
print(inputDir)
for pptx in inputDir:
        file = direc + pptx
        print(file)
        Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(os.path.abspath(file))
        #Presentation.Slides[1].Export("e:\\temp\\1.jpg", "JPG", 800, 600);
        num = Presentation.Slides.count
        print(num)
        output = "/output/"
        for i in range(num):
            Presentation.Slides[i+1].Export(os.path.abspath(output) + str(i+1) +".jpg", "JPG", 800, 600)
```

I'm trying to batch export pptx to image and I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQXgK.png), even though I can easily export the pptx to image manually

Comment: Never post links to image of text (whether of source code or errors), just copy paste and format. [ask]

Comment: Permissions issue. I'm guessing it's something like:
```Go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View > UNCHECK the box next to Enable Data Execution Prevention Mode.```

Comment: There's no Enable Data Execution Prevention Mode